# mysql not able to handle images

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

I used Java code to store images into my mysql database having datatype longBlob. 
However, when I try to see the image using SELECT query I get this as a result: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you've attached doesn't actually show if there's anything in the table - it's just showing the column headers. Run something like this to double check:

```
select count(1) from Image;
```

That said, even if the binary data was stored in the table, the command line mysql app (or MySQL Workbench for that matter) aren't able to display images as images. All they know is that there's binary data in that column, not that it's an image. If you want to display the image, then you'll need to get that binary data out and interpret it as image data (e.g. save to a file with a JPG or PNG or whatever extension).